# Java multiple arguments dot notation - Varargs

Tags: java, constants

I've just acknowledged dot notation for method declaration with multiple arguments
like this:

```
public function getURLs(URL... urls){
    for(int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
        // walk through array of arguments
    }
}
```

And using like this

```
getURLs(url1, url2, url3);
```

where those method arguments are converted implicitly into `URL[] urls`

1. Did I understand its behavior properly?
2. Where is documentation to this syntax?
3. From which version of JRE (J2ME,J2SE,Dalvik) is this supported?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, that is how it works. The arguments are automatically put into an array. The argument "urls" behaves like a `URL[]`. [Varargs are documented here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). They were introduced in Java 1.5, so, are available in J2SE 1.5+, and all of Android since it supports Java 1.5+ language features. No version of JavaME/J2ME supports it.

Comment: does this array preserve the order ?

Comment: Of course, wouldn't be much use if args were passed in an arbitrary order