# What is the best way to send a method a dynamic number of variables?

Tags: java, arrays, int, variadic-functions

I have a java program with a method that will consistently receive a different number of `int` values. What is the best way to send it the `ints`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?   just call the method with arguments...  methodName( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 )

Comment: i want a dynamic number of arguments

Comment: You say you HAVE a method that takes a dynamic length argument set... and ask how you call it.  Dynamic arguments are so you can call it with any number of arguments, so one time you can call it with 1,2,3,4 and another time you can call it with 3,5,2,1,43,5,3,32.

Answer (score 3):

A construct called [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) (or an arbitrary number of arguments) helps you.

```
method(int... ints) { ... }
```

Then, varargs will be turned into `int[]` by the compiler.

---

OK, how to call those methods?

```
method(1, 2, 3);
method(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

---

About the question in the comments:

```
method(Arrays.stream(yourStringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray());
```

You may convert `String[]` to `int[]` firstly, and then pass the result to the `method`.

Comment: would you consider this method better than sending it an array? i originally have a string array that contains the ints , which are the ints im sending to the method.

Comment: Using varargs is perfect because you can pass it an array OR many parameters with commas. It's your choice.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(s).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()` and pass `int[]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like below you can do, making use of **dot notation for method declaration with multiple arguments**

```
public TestClass 
{
  public void process(int... variables)
  {
    // process your variables,
   // Iterate through variables
  }
}
```

Plus refer this, [Java multiple arguments dot notation - Varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539033/java-multiple-arguments-dot-notation-varargs)

Comment: thanks , what is this called? is the "..." an operator?